# How to install MongoDB on Debian 11 from source without breaking Debian?

Tags: debian

MongoDB isn't available in Debian 11. Only [10 and 9 are supported](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/).

So I want to install it from source, but I want to install MongoDB without breaking Debian if I upgrade or update.

Would you please guide me?

Comment: Dangerous path to take, install the buster version.

Comment: I've installed a docker and installed mongodb on it, not it is running smoothly in debian 11 . :)

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan it stopped at Debian stretch. The licence change to SSPLv1 made Debian abandon this software (eg: it's [not open-source/OSI-approved](https://opensource.org/node/1099))

Comment: Why none forked the AGPL version?